# invalidate multiple rectangles or regions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, invalidation, onpaint

I'm having problems with `Invalidate()` because it calls `OnPaint` before I'm ready...
`Invalidate(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height))` works fine when I need to repaint one and only one area, but what I need to do is create a collection of rectangles to invalidate and then use `Update()` method to repaint all invalidated zones. I'm a bit lost between `Invalidate()` and `Update()`: how to use them and what's the clean way to do so.

I need to achieve this because I'm working on cellular automatons such as "Langton's ant" or "Conway's Game of life". Small grids are not a problem but with big sized grids (700x500) the painting is a very important issue.

So my question is how do I invalidate X rectangles without calling `OnPaint` at each invalidation and then call `OnPaint` to refresh only the specified areas (X rectangles would = at least hundreds, thousands for sure)?

Comment: I presume this is a Windows Forms application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling [`Invalidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx) method does not immediately raise the [`Paint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) event. It only sets the specified region as *invalid* and queues a paint event. Next call to [`Invalidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx) only adds up the region to previously invalidated region. It puts a new `Paint` event only if there is no `Paint` event in the queue.

From the **Remarks** section of the [`Invalidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx) method:

> Calling the Invalidate method does not force a synchronous paint; to force a synchronous paint, call the [`Update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx) method after calling the Invalidate method. When this method is called with no parameters, the entire client area is added to the update region.

---

**More explanation:**

Windows Forms technology is a wrapper on `Win32`'s `user32` library. To understand under the hoods of the paint event, you need to know how user32 works.

#### [Message Queue:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx)

Every process in windows has a [message queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx). When anything happens to a window that belongs to the process, Windows pushes an event into the [message queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx) of the process. There is a [message loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx#loop) in every application, that extracts the messages from the queue (by calling [`GetMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx)) and dispatches the message (calls appropriate function, called a [`Window Procedure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632593.aspx), by calling [DispatchMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644934.aspx)). So the messages are being processed one after another. It means that when a message is being processed, no other message can be processed.
That's why when you do a time-consuming operation in a form (withoud starting a new thread), the application stops respongind: You are stuck in processing one message (for example `Click` event of a button), so the application cannot process other messages (mouse event, painting events, etc.).

In Windows Forms, [`Application.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run.aspx) method runs the message loop of the application. Messages are passed to [Control.WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) method and this method determines the appropriate `OnXxxx` method to call (`OnKeyPress`, `OnMouseMove`, `OnResize`, etc.), and that method raises the respective event (`KeyPress`, `MouseMove`, `Rezie`, etc).

#### [WM_PAINT:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx)

When a program's window needs to be painted (for example when it is first shown or it is restored from minimized state), Windows queues a [`WM_PAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx) messages into the message queue, only if there is no unprocessed [`WM_PAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx) for the window in the message queue. Also the message loop only extract the [`WM_PAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx) message from the queue only when there is no other message in the queue. Qoute from the [`WM_PAINT` page in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx):

> GetMessage returns the WM_PAINT message when there are no other messages in the application's message queue, and DispatchMessage sends the message to the appropriate window procedure.

In Windows Forms, [`WM_PAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx) translates to `OnPaint` method which raises the [`Paint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) event.

When you call `Invalidate` (which calls the Win32 [`InvalidateRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002.aspx) function) several times in a single method, the `Paint` event still didn't get the chance to be raised. The current event that is being processed must be finished, also other messages that are sent in the mean time should be processed, then the `Paint` event is raised.

Please follow the links in the answer and read them thoroughly.

Comment: I don't get it... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate%28v=vs.71%29.aspx : this says "Invalidates a specific region of the control and causes a paint message to be sent to the control." that means OnPaint is called right ? that's whats happening for me ! Invalidate() calls protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e).

Comment: @thomas: Invalidate() does not call OnPaint(). It ultimately calls the WinAPI function InvalidateRect() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002(v=vs.85).aspx) which will queue up a WM_PAINT message eventually.

Comment: @thomas I clarified the answer. Hope that helps you understand the mechanism. This is all original content, I wrote for this answer :-) Let me know if you want more explanation in some areas.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn Thanks for the help and pointing me in the right direction. I'm reading all the doc... there is a lot to understand but it's worth it.